# Al hacer POST no recupero correctamente el valor de un radio button

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Intento describir mi escenario.
Tengo una vista que contiene dos radio buttons y en función de cual se seleccione, se muestra una vista parcial u otra.

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TipoVP, new String("VP_A".ToCharArray()), new { @checked = "checked" })
 <span class="custom-control-label">Vista parcial A</span>
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TipoVP, new String("VP_B".ToCharArray()))
 <span class="custom-control-label">Vista parcial B</span>
```

Como se aprecia, al entrar, por defecto se muestra la vista parcial A porque tiene definido el cheked a true.

Las vistas parciales se muestran en esta div:

```
  <div id="vistaparcial">
     @Html.Action("GetVistaParcial", "miControlador")
  </div>
```

También tengo un código javascript para mostrar/ocultar las vistas parciales en función del radio button que se selecciona.

```
 $("[name=TipoVP]").on('change', function () {
    var $rb = $(this);
    alert($rb.val());

    $.ajax({
       url: '/miControlador/GetVistaParcial/',
       data: { tipov: $rb.val() },
       success: function (respuesta) {
          $("#vistaparcial").html(respuesta);
       }
    });
 });
```

El método de la acción está así:

```
 public ActionResult GetVistaParcial(string tipov)
 {
    if (tipov == null || tipov == "VP_A")
       return PartialView("_PartialView_A");
    else
       return PartialView("_PartialView_B");
    }
 }
```

Hasta aquí en principio todo parece funcionar bien, al cargar la vista aparece en primer lugar la vista parcial A, cuando pulso los radio buttons se muestra y ocultan correctamente, pero... Si tengo seleccionada la vista parcial B y hago un POST para enviar los datos al controlador, al método de acción que ha de procesar los datos me llega correctamente el valor del radio button seleccionado (VP_B), pero luego en la acción GetVistaParcial, el valor que le llega al parámetro es null, con lo que me muestra la vista parcial que no toca.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que al realizar un POST, se conserve el valor del radio button seleccionado?

Añado esta información para responder a los comentarios de Leandro y aportar más información a la pregunta inicial.

Mi método de acción que debe procesar los datos estaría así:

```
 public ActionResult Index(miViewModel vm)
 {
    /* Aquí en vm.TipoVP tengo VP_A o VP_B según la selección */
    //Realizar acciones
    /* Devuelvo el modelo a la vista */
    return View(vm);
 }
```

Una vez se ejecuta el return, en la vista, tengo la línea:

```
 @Html.Action("GetVistaParcial", "miControlador", new { tipov = Model.TipoVP } )
```

El problema es que **no sé cómo referenciar** el contenido de Model.TipoVP para asignarlo a tipov en el HtmlAction().

Comment: En tu accion `GetVistaParcial` el parametro se llama `tipov` y en el ajax lo llamas `tipodir`. De seguro siempre te llega nulo, por lo que en el caso `A` siempre se ejecuta bien. Si quitas la validacion del null en la accion tambien te funciona el caso `A`?.

Comment: Orlando, se me ha escapado en el copiar y pegar. Disculpa la confusión. El problema lo tengo después de hace el submit en el POST, que no consigo establecer el valor con el que envié el modelo al controlador. Si quito la validación del null como dices, me peta la comparación, ya que el parámetro me viene a nulo.

Answer (score 0):

Para cnservar el valor del radio button debera ser enviado como parte del `submit` al action que recibe el `post`, entonces lo envias nuevamente en el render del view

Si en el cshtml defines

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.tipov,"VP_A")
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.tipov,"VP_B")
```

entonces en el action lo recibes para asignarlo como parte del modelo

```
public class xxModel{
   //resto propiedades
   public string tipov {get;set;}
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Actionpost(xxModel model){
    //aqui codigo

    return(model);
}
```

puedes cambiar el valor del model, pero si lo devuelve asi como llego vuelves a enviar la seleccion que se renderiza en la view

Comment: Leandro, ya lo tengo así puesto. y a 'Actionpost' llega correctamente del valor del radio button. El problema es que al cargarse la vista, la línea `@Html.Action("GetVistaParcial", "miControlador")`llama a la acción que devuelve la vista parcial y el valor del parámetro `tipov`es nulo.

Comment: pero a ese action debes pasarle un model con el valor del radio, sino le pasas un model no tendra un dato que definir para el control, es incorrecto lo que comentas que se pierde, es que en realidas nunca lo asignas porque no le pasas que valor debe tener

Comment: Ya entiendo lo que me dices, pero al cargarse la vista, en la línea que llama a la vista parcial, no consigo obtener el valor del rb seleccionado, ni del control ni del modelo, entiendo que debería ir así: `@Html.Action("GetVistaParcial", "miControlador", new { tipodir = **de alguna manera el valor del rb**)` _**pero no sé cómo obtener el valor para pasarlo como parámetro.**_

Comment: exacto esa es la idea, la captura del valor del radiobutton entiendo deberias hacerla en el action que recibe el post, por lo tanto tu viewmodel de la view principal deberia tenerlo, es como un pasamanos que harias entre la view principal y la parcial (que renderizas con el action) ya que ambas estan dentro de un mismo Html.BeginForm()

Comment: como mencione en la respuesta, el valor del radio lo recibes en el action que recibe el post del submit y debes enviarlo como respuesta en el model para tenerlo disponible, sino el valor se pierde

Comment: Leandro, eso ya lo hago. Pero al volver del POST, en la vista, la línea que llama a la acción GetVistaParcial para que se muestre la vista que corresponde, el valor de tipodir es nulo, no se porqué.